# How can I write these char arrays in a nicer way?

Tags: c, arrays

Right now I have an array of char arrays, which I'm using to store font data:

```
const char * const FONT[] = {
    "\x48" "a44448", //0
    "\x27" "m\x48" "m\x40", //1
    "\x06" "a46425" "m\x00" "m\x80", //2 
    "\x06" "a46425" "a42425", //3
    "\x83" "m\x03" "m\x68" "m\x60", //4
    "\x88" "m\x08" "m\x04" "m\x44" "a42424" "m\x00", //5
    "\x02" "a42428" "a84842", //6
    "\x08" "m\x88" "m\x20", //7
    "\x44" "A46428" "a42428", //8
    "\x86" "a46428" "m\x60", //9
    ...
```

Is there a way to write this in a more readable way, but still have it computed at compile time?
For example, something like:

```
#define start(x,y) //somehow create '\x<x><y>'. start(3,4) -> '\x34'
#define arc(x,y,rx,ry,a) //evaluate to {'a','<x>','<y>','<rx>','<ry>','<a>'}. arc(1,2,3,4,5) -> {'a','1','2','3','4','5'}

const char * const FONT[] = {
    start(4,8) arc(4,4, 4,4, 8) "", //somehow concatenate them
    ...
```

---

Also, why can I use string literals but not char array literals:
(This doesn't work)

```
const char * const FONT[] = {
    {'\x48','a','4','4','4','4','8','\0'}, //0
```

But this works:

```
const char X[] = {'\x48','a','4','4','4','4','8','\0'};
const char * const FONT[] = {
    X,
...
```

Comment: *(This doesn't work)* is because you want `char [][]` rather than `char *[]`.

Comment: @EugeneSh.I tried that, but it says I have to give a size for the second dimension. The arrays are all different lengths though, so I can't do that.

Comment: You can give it the maximum possible.

Comment: Yep, the "" is a bit of a hack since the compiler will allocate memory for the strings for you and you then define an array of pointers to the strings. You can't do that with {1,2,3} notation. You have to define every character separately and then build an array pointers like you did with `X[]`.

Comment: Note, that `'\x48'` is the same as `0x48`. This can save you some trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to write this in a more readable way, but still have it
>   computed at compile time? For example, something like:
>
> ```
> #define start(x,y) //somehow create '\x<x><y>'. start(3,4) -> '\x34'
> #define arc(x,y,rx,ry,a) //evaluate to {'a','<x>','<y>','<rx>','<ry>','<a>'}. arc(1,2,3,4,5) -> {'a','1','2','3','4','5'}
>
> const char * const FONT[] = {
>     start(4,8) arc(4,4, 4,4, 8) "", //somehow concatenate them
>     ...
> ```

You can implement your `start()` macro with use of the preprocessor's stringification (`#`) and token-pasting (`##`) operators.  You need to be a little careful with these, however, to account for the fact that their arguments are not first macro-expanded.  Where you do want macro expansion, you can achieve it by interposing an extra layer of macro.  For example:

```
// Stringify the argument (without expansion)
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x

// Expand the argument and stringify the result
#define STRINGIFY_EXPANSION(x) STRINGIFY(x)

// Assumes that the arguments should not themselves be expanded
#define MAKE_HEX(x, y) \ ## x ## y

#define start(x,y) STRINGIFY_EXPANSION(MAKE_HEX(x,y))
```

Similarly, you can implement your `arc()` macro as

```
// No macro expansion wanted here, neither at this level nor before stringifying
#define arc(x,y,rx,ry,a) STRINGIFY(x ## y ## rx ## ry ## a)
```

(Technically, that creates a string literal token that implies a null terminator, not the unterminated `char` array you described, but that's what you really want anyway.)

> Also, why can I use string literals but not char array literals: (This
>   doesn't work)
>
> ```
> const char * const FONT[] = {
>     {'\x48','a','4','4','4','4','8','\0'}, //0
> ```
>
> But this works:
>
> ```
> const char X[] = {'\x48','a','4','4','4','4','8','\0'};
> const char * const FONT[] = {
>     X,
> ...
> ```

Largely because those are *not* array literals.  They are plain initializers.  Initializers provide a sequence of values used to initialize an object being declared; when that object is a compound one, such as an array or struct, multiple values presented in its initializer provide initial values for some or all of its members.  The members of your array `FONT` are of type `char *`, and those pointers are what an initializer provides values for.  They furthermore have no deeper structure, so no nested braces are expected.

An array literal might look like this:

```
(const char[]) {'\x48','a','4','4','4','4','8','\0'}
```

And, because arrays decay to pointers in initializers, too, just as they do most everywhere else, you indeed can use array literals to initialize your array of pointers:

```
const char * const FONT[] = {
    (const char[]) {'\x48','a','4','4','4','4','8','\0'},
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This set of macro's should do what you want :

```
#define str(s) #s
#define start(px,py) str(\x##px##py)
#define arc(x,y,rx,ry,pa) str(a##x##y##rx##ry##pa)

const char * const FONT[] = {
    start(4,8) arc(4,4, 4,4, 8),
}
```

This makes use of the [`#` and `##` operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) (aka stringization resp. concatenation operators).

And results in the following pre-compiler output :

```
const char * const FONT[] = {
    "\x48" "a44448",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A nicer way would be to write it all in hexadecimal notation even for printable characters. But given the different length that would still be a mess.

How about loading the font from a file at runtime or linking it in as binary blob from a file? There isn't really a good way of making binary data look good in source.

Answer (score 1):

You have almost got the reason. You declare an *array of pointers* because you have rows of different sizes. So in `const char * const FONT[] = {...`, `FONT` is an array of `const` pointers to arrays of `const char`s. A litteral string is a const char array so it will decay to a pointer that will be used for the initialization of `FONT`. If you first declare a char array and use its name, things go well too, because here again the array decays to a pointer.

But in C `{'\x48','a','4','4','4','4','8','\0'}` is not by itself an array but only an initialization list that can only be used to initialize a character array. For example:

```
char arr_ok[] = { '1', '2', '3', '\0' }; // correct initialization of a char[4]
char *ptr_ko = { '1', '2', '3', '\0' };  // wrong initialization of a char* (should not compile)
```

That means that the initialization list is not an array and cannot decay to a pointer.

---

Things would be different for a 2D array:

```
char arr2D[][9] = { { '1', '2', '3' }, { '4', '5', '6' }, { '7', '8', '9'} };
```

This line initializes the 3 sub arrays with resp. '1','2','3' '4','5','6 and '7','8','9'. But it cannot be used for an array of pointers